how to use Jquery with go-admin (SPA)
I am developing an administrative panel using Go-Admin, which operates as a Single Page Application (SPA). I've added custom jQuery scripts to enhance certain pages, but I'm encountering an issue: the scripts execute correctly on a full page load but do not re-run after navigating to other parts of the SPA.
What i have done:

Placed my jQuery script in the footer.
Tried invoking the script directly on document load and inside a $(document).ready() function.

I'm looking for a way to reliably reinitialize my jQuery scripts after each page transition within the SPA. Ideally, this would be something that could be integrated easily with Go-Admin's existing JavaScript lifecycle, but I'm not sure if Go-Admin provides hooks or events for this.

You can use listen for change in route and reinitialize your jQuery scripts. Code samples will help solve it faster.
